# Missing columns in test set

Tags: classification, missing-data

Maybe this question is obvious but I couldn't find something related.

I have a classification task, the training data contains a bunch of images and a CSV file with some columns of categories related to the images; hence every image has ~6 values for each category in the CSV.

But in the test set CSV, I have fewer columns.
One of the missing columns is related to the content of the image. I assume that I can train a classifier that will predict the missing column and then use the prediction in the destination classifier but since this can be erroneous is it a good approach?

or should I train the model without the values that not appear in the test set?
What's better to do?

Comment: The second approach seems strictly better than the first.

Answer (score 0):

**Missing values** - that is some subject, see [missing values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341740/handling-missing-data-for-a-neural-network/341838#341838). It all *depends* - that is the plausible answer. If your missing column is unnecessary for the classifier as assessed *on the training set* (just leave it out, make a new classifier and train again), then you can just train your NN without that column right from the start. If on the other hand that column contains important information then it cannot be missed - that is - when you want the best performing classifier.

**Imputation** - your only choice would be to predict it from the (pixel) data. However, such a prediction will not add any information to the original NN in the first place. This is so because the pixel values already themselves contain the information used to predict the most likely outcome of the missing column.

See further the reference on [missing values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341740/handling-missing-data-for-a-neural-network/341838#341838) for an explanation on the missing data mechanisms.